# can I design a User Interface to run on the arduino and display it with VGA?

Tags: serial

I know you can design a user-interface in any language you choose and Link it with a Arduino via serial Port, but I am asking if I can design user-interface to run on the Arduino WITHOUT the need for an external laptop/desktop and display the user interface on a screen (like via VGA) ? and HOW ?

Comment: Only in the most crude and blocky manner.  There are a few game systems which come close.  realistically you should use something else; today small LCD or OLED displays are all of cheaper, more compact, and far easier to drive; if you really want VGA use a small FPGA or fast MCU for that.  But your question is far **too broad** to be a fit here - stack exchange sites are about specifics.

Comment: What are you asking? Can you connect a LCD? An OLED display? A 8x8 LED module (or a string of them)? There are lots of ways of doing user interface. And [VGA is possible](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11608).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget VGA. Arduino is not capable of that.

For display you can use a 16x2 LCD (only chars, not graphics) or an OLED display, which have graphic capabilities. There are in size from 0.96". There BW, but alse color models and touch sensitive ones. For input you use push buttons, or keypad.

Today best option for display is some model with I2C or SPI interfaces (to minimize wiring).

There thousand of projects in Internet. Search "Arduino OLED keypad" and you will find projects like http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-OLED-Calculator/:

[image]

This hardware impose some limits in the UI (thank god). What you have is a tradicional menu system: you present a menu, user choose an option, Arduino execute it. No help, no dropbox, no autocompletion, nothing, only the most basic "Press 1 for ..."

EDIT:

As Nick Gammon stated, it's possible to drive a VGA display from an Arduino, like [this post](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11608) and this [other](https://github.com/smaffer/vgax) shows. The resolution are  20 characters wide by 30 characters deep (160 x 480 pixels) for the monochrome version and 120 x 60 pixels for the four colors version.

However, that capabilities doesn't match any of the standard VGA capabilities:

> The VGA supports both All Points Addressable graphics modes, and
>   alphanumeric text modes. Standard graphics modes are:
>
> ```
> 640×480 in 16 colors or monochrome[2] (the latter matching IBM's lesser Multi-Color Graphics Array standard)
> 640×350 or 640×200 in 16 colors or monochrome (EGA compatibility mode)
> 320×200 in 4 or 16 colors
> 320×200 in 256 colors (Mode 13h)
> ```

The proposed alternatives achieves less resolution than a 1981 Sinclair ZX-81 (24 lines of 32 chars), takes two timers and half of Arduino RAM minimum (the color example left you with 200 bytes RAM and takes a third timer with it).

So, in practical terms, VGA is not an option.

Comment: so I can't simply create a GUI (like the u create with java/swing or qt/c++) and run it on the Arduino ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis. Thank god not! So many hours wasted ajusting the graphic UI in a PC. Think more in the line of old cell phones, very simple, shallow menu. You have to think in screens of 4 lines x 20-40 chars (tipically with OLED). Arduino is not a PC; you don't sit in front of it all day long; you just need a UI for a quick check or simple action. You don't do data entry on Arduino; if you need to input a great amount of date, better downlad it from a PC, tablet or smartphone.

Comment: @MekacherAnis. If UI is a issue, I will choose a NodeMCU instead of Arduino, and use MQTT to control NodeMCU with a GUI running in a smartphone, table or desktop PC. Have a look at MQTT.

Comment: thaaaank u for this clarification, my problem is that I considered the Arduino a PC while it's simply a programmable microcontroller, I think I'll get back to the idea of designing with java or c++ as I have experience with those languages

Comment: @MekacherAnis. If you want to control devices in real time, it have to be Arduino (or similar). If you just want a small format PC, look at  Raspberry Pi. Or combine both: Raspberry for UI, Arduino for device control.

Comment: *Forget VGA. Arduino is not capable of that.* - [Yes it is](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11608)

Comment: @NickGammon. Well, you **can** display something in a VGA monitor, but monochrome output and 20 characters wide by 30 characters deep (160 x 480 pixels) is not the same VGA that the OP is looking for. VGA means at least 640x480 with 256 colors. Less than that you have CGA (or Hercules even).

Comment: S/he said "like via VGA". If you want to display "cooling on" or "cooling off" that would be adequate.

Comment: @NickGammon. While driven a VGA display from an Arduino is posible, devoting half of Arduino RAM and two timers just achieve less resolution than a Sinclair ZX81 doesn't sound appealing.

Comment: It's something I wouldn't do, because a LCD display would be more logical. :)

Comment: @NickGammon no what I really meant by VGA is a beautiful graphical interactive interface that looks appealing not a an MS DOS kinda of thing, anyway thank u both for this clarification

Comment: @MekacherAnis If you wan't a fancy GUI with Arduino, look up Nextion displays.

Comment: @gre_gor that's really good, cool idea, I'll keep that in mind, but it's a bit small for my taste, I'm looking to control a computer monitor, and as explained it seems out of reach with the use of just an arduino

Comment: @MekacherAnis You will need a Raspberry Pi for that.

Comment: @gre_gor yes it seems like I need one... thank you for your help